# Reduce image size without resolution change

Tags: photoshop

how to prepare clear and clarity UI design with lower image file size in photoshop for iphone UI?
In my Iphone app due to large size images my app size increased enormously.So Is there any other way to reduce the size of the images but i need the clarity shouldn't change..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Photoshop usually does a pretty good job of creating efficient images, however, you can normally losslessly compress them further using Yahoo's [smush.it](http://smush.it) tool or a command line tool.  Personally I use [optipng](http://optipng.sourceforge.net/) which you can install via MacPorts.

You can also experiment with removing the @2x images entirely and just submitting with 2x resolution normal images. In most cases, the non-retina devices will downsample the larger images, but always worth testing on an actual device first.